# How to put 3 GridViews inside a Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a long table, so I want to split it into 3 GridView. Each GridView will have different headers (different columns from the DB). I want to use one SqlDataSource. For that, I am thinking to use a Repeater and then put 3 GridViews inside it.

Since I am using StoredProcedure that asks for one parameter in order to specify the headers of each GridView, I set the that parameter as HiddenField but even with that I did not get any result.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("GroupID")%>' />

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" 
                DataKeyNames="BadgeNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                       SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT GroupID
                                from courses">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem you should have to `plan` or `design` the dataSource - may be you can use `Linq` or `Entity Model` or `DataSet`. I think the `SqlDataSource` is not appropriate here.

In current code-snippet, you should have to design SELECT - sql statement with *where* condition/clause of `SqlDataSource` for `GridView` controls.